# Passing the value from a group of radio buttons to the servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, for-loop, radio-button

Greetings of the day !!!

I have created a jsp file as follow :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="TestAms" method="post">
<%
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        %>
            <input type="radio" name="<%= i%>" value="<%=i %>">
        <%
    }
%>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This program creates 5 radio buttons in a loop having name and value same as the loop variable.Now I want to get the values of the radio buttons in the servlet. The code for my servlet is as follow :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class TestAms extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)   throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    String s[] = new String[5];
    s[i] = request.getParameter("<%= i%>"); 
    out.println(s[i]);
    }
}
}
```

But I am ending with only 5 "null" values. I know where the problem is. But I am unable to find a way to pass the loop variables to request.getParameter() method. Please help me .....  Thnx in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java, you should write:

```
s[i] = request.getParameter(Integer.toString(i));
```

<%= ... %> are JSP scriptlet, not for Java class.